# Can I search on internet through the RUN prompt in windows?

Tags: windows-8, shortcuts, run-dialog

I was used to keeping some shortcuts of my program in a folder which is included in PATH, so whenever I want to launch any of them, I simply hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then the name of the program. As for websites, I used the shortcut of Chrome, and append the url in that shortcut's properties's `Target` bar.

Now my question is: Is there a way that allows me to search on internet directly from the RUN prompt? As for now I have to hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>(Name of my shortcut of Chrome), at last input the search string in address bar. As you can see, there are three steps, I want to cut it to two.

To be more specific, for example, when I input `CH target` in RUN prompt, I expect it to open Chrome, and search `target` string using my default search engine of Chrome. Similarly, if I input `IE target`, I hope it can launch IE and search using my default search engine of IE.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want to search using a specific site? Do you want the results to be displayed in chrome or otherwise?

Comment: Edited to be more specific.@Raystafarian

Comment: `start www.google.com/search?q=test` will open the browser and search google, from command prompt. You don't want to specify the website in the prompt as this adds to the time it takes, correct?

Comment: I think there is a little misunderstanding. I want to search directly from the RUN prompt, not the command prompt. And yes, I don't want to specify the website, I want it to use my default search engine, like when I input some key words in my browser's address bar and hit `Enter`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I did misunderstand. Apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make a bat-file called CH and place it in PATH, and let it look something like this:

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] (
    explorer.exe "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
) else (
    explorer.exe "https://www.google.com/search?q=%1+%2+%3+%4+%5+%6+%7+%8+%9" 
)
exit
```

Explorer.exe opens the url in default browser, and with this you can search for up to nine words, if that's not enough there are ways to shift through all commandline arguments in batch, but nine ought to suffice. If you only search for one word, google will ignore the extra +'s.

Edit: Now if you don't pass it any arguments, i.e. only type CH it will open chrome to its default homepage.

Edit2:
Here are some more you can use aswell:

```
I'm Feeling Lucky: "http://www.google.com/search?q=%1+%2+%3+%4+%5+%6+%7+%8+%9&btnI"
IMDB: "http://www.imdb.com/find?q=%1+%2+%3+%4+%5+%6+%7+%8+%9"
Wikipedia: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%1+%2+%3+%4+%5+%6+%7+%8+%9"
```

To clarify, this works from the RUN prompt and from the commandline prompt.

Comment: Exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

wait for [Windows 8.1 which offers a search which displays Bing results for your search term](http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/search/archive/2013/05/30/8-1.aspx):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since explanation of the question suggests that you want to reduce the steps in searching through your default search engine with the help of keyboard shortcuts. My answer will help you do just that.

Pin your default browser to your taskbar.

Press "Windows" + "the index of your browser in the taskbar".

Say your browser is at the 5th location on your taskbar, starting from left. Then press "windows" + "5" and your browser will open directly.

you can set your default search engine to look for your keyword on your browser by doing this in Firefox.

1)Type 'about:config' in address bar. Now it is advised that do not change anything here which you have no idea about. This will also be evident from the warning which you get....
Moving on, a page with 4 columns will get displayed.

2)Type 'keyword.URL' in filter box. Just one option will be visible now.

3)Right-Click on that option and select modify. A box will be displayed.

4)Enter any of the following string for corresponding search engine:

For Google: "http://www.google.co.in/search?btnG=Google+Search&q="

For Wikipedia: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?fulltext=Search&search="

For Yahoo: "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p="

I hope you are getting the drift by looking at the above queries.

Now the next time Firefox is opened through you one step keyboard shortcut. Just type in your keyword in your URL bar and off you fly.

Do your bit of research for finding similar tweaks in other browsers if Firefox is not the browser of your choice.

Comment: Sorry for my finicky, but I prefer a more uniform way and have a strange interest to keep my desktop and taskbar clean, so both of them in my computer is empty, since I open nearly everything with `Win+R`. Thanks anyway, if no better solution appeared, I will accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can... you just need to do this

1. Go to Run
2. copy/paste or type
   *www.google.com/search?q=*
3. and then the query you want to search

If there is a space in between words just add a plus sign +

For example: www.google.com/search?q=**super+user**

Answer (score 0):

Create a .bat file. This code in it should help you -

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] (
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
) else (
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe""https://www.google.com/search?q=%~1" 
)
exit
```

**Notice %~1 : This means you can give search keywords with spaces.**